# RealityKit – How can I hide a specific joint in ARSkeleton?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have an application that uses [body motion tracking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/607/) like in WWDC 2019. I am trying to have a character one to one mapped within my body and replacing the character's head with my head.

Is it possible to hide the head joint to accomplish this feature?

Comment: @AndyFedoroff Hide it, the example project WWDC provides a robot character which tracks motion tracking. I want to be able to hide the head joint on the head real time, so hide the robot's head real time as it tracks my motion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RealityKit 2.0, I don't see any option to hide/remove/disable a `.head` joint from the `ARSkeleton3D` hierarchy. Most likely, the best way would be to disable the `.head` joint in the virtual 3D character's skeleton.